# Intuition Behind Homomorphisms of Representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I have recently started learning about group representations, and the definition for homomorphisms between representations is bothering me a little:

> For two representations of $G$, $(\rho, V)$, $(\tau, W)$, the set of all homomorphism from one to the other is defined to be
>
> $$Hom_G(V, W) := \{ T: V \rightarrow W\ |\ T\circ \rho(g) = \tau(g) \circ T,\ \forall g \in G \}$$

The general definition of a homomorphism is:

> **Any** mapping between objects which preserves the operations of those objects.

---

**Firstly**: How is this a mapping from $(\rho, V)$ to $(\tau, W)$? How would such a mapping make sense, as $(\rho, V)$ and $(\tau, W)$ are functions, as opposed to a collection.

**Secondly**: I see how this definition preserves operations across $G$, and thus across the representations, however, does this set satisfy the **any** property? That is, for all $g_1,g_2 \in G$,

$$T\circ\rho(g_1g_2) = T\circ\rho(g_1)\circ\rho(g_2) = \tau(g_3)\circ T \Rightarrow (g_3 = g_1g_2)$$

---

I see how this definition of homomorphisms between representations yields some powerful results, however, is this a crude use of the word homomorphism? Should I see this as merely a definition, or is there some nice intuition behind it?

Thanks for any input on the matter! Much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, a representation is **neither** a set or a function: it is a **pair**, the "$V$-half" of which is a set (+ some structure) and the "$\rho$-half" of which is a function. The mapping here "lives on the set parts." This is exactly analogous to how (for example) a group isn't a set but rather a set **plus** some additional stuff.

Comment: A homomorphism of group representations (or more generally sets equipped with a group action) $f: X \to Y$ is also called a *$G$-equivariant function*: performing the action and then the function $f(g \cdot x)$ is the same as performing the function and then the action $g \cdot f(x)$. Viewing $f$ as linking the spaces $X$ and $Y$, it says that the spaces move in a compatible way when acted on by $G$. As for the "any" property, a $G$-space or representation does not need to be faithful: $g \cdot x = x$ need not imply that $g = 1$.

Comment: Very helpful. I now understand much better what a representation and a homomorphism of representations, are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A representation of $G$ is just a vector space $V$ with an additional "scalar multiplication":

For $g \in G$ and $v \in V$, we have a new vector $gv \in V$. This operation has to satisfy the following axioms:

- For each $g \in G$, left-multiplication by $g$ is a linear map from $V$ to $V$, that is to say, $g(\lambda v_1+v_2) = \lambda(gv_1)+gv_2$ for any $v_1,v_2 \in V$ and any $\lambda$ in the underlying field.
- For any $g_1,g_2 \in G$ one has that $(g_1g_2)v = g_1(g_2v)$ for all $v \in V$.
- If $e$ is the identity element of $G$, then $ev = v$ for all $v \in V$.

---

Thus, a homomorphism between representations of $G$, $V_1$ and $V_2$, is just a linear map $T \colon V_1 \to V_2$ that also satisfies that $$T(gv) = gT(v)$$ for all $v \in V_1$ and all $g \in G$. Note that, in the above equality, yuxtaposition with $g$ has two different meanings, just as same as when one writes things like $T(\lambda v)=\lambda T(v)$ in the definition of linear map.

Answer (score 0):

In this context it makes sense to talk about modules. With your notation, $V$ and $W$ are modules of the group algebra $FG$ via $g\cdot v:=\rho(g)(v)$ where $F$ is the underlying field. Now $f\colon V\to W$ is a homomorphism of modules if $f(gv)=gf(v)$ for all $g\in G$ and $v\in V$. This is equivalent to $f\circ\rho(g)=\rho(g)\circ f$ for all $g\in G$.